# ag-grid - agDateColumnFilter - how to format the filter value we can enter

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

https://blog.ag-grid.com/valueformatters-part-2/

We can enter a year with 6 digit, is there a way to restrict so that we can enter only 4 digit year ?

[image]